# AmdGPU fail: Error Failed to initialize parser -125!

Tags: amdgpu

I'm rather new to Linux and installed Ubuntu in my T495. It works pretty well, but once in a while when booting, the screen stays black. When I look it up in the syslog it states:

```
[drm:amdgpu_cs_ioctl [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to initialize parser -125!
```

It's annoying that every once in a while I have to force turn off.
Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

While it's a bit late, this behavior is the subject of [this open issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1870971). There is a hacky workaround described there, but also the mention that

1. This issue appears to be fixed in more recent versions of the kernel than ubuntu currently is using and
2. The issue does not occur when plugged into power.

I have an identical issue ([my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259959/ubuntu-20-04-non-deterministically-hanging-during-boot/1261705#1261705)) and have opted to just be careful to boot on battery power and wait it out.

Comment: It's 2022 and this still happens to me on battery power a few times a day.